# Python UDP server ERROR

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, udp

I'm trying to build a UDP server which accepts multiple clients (using threads)

```
import socket
import threading
bind_ip = "0.0.0.0"
bind_port = 9999
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind((bind_ip,bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (bind_ip,bind_port)
# this is our client-handling thread

def handle_client(client_socket):
    # print out what the client sends
    request = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print "[*] Received: %s" % request
    # send back a packet
    client_socket.send("ACK!")
    client_socket.close()

while True:

    client,addr = server.accept()
    print "[*] Accepted connection from: %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])
    # spin up our client thread to handle incoming data
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

I seem to be hitting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Python_codes/UDP_server.py", line 7, in <module>
    server.listen(5)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Can you please assist me. Thanks in advance.